# Anaconda libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found

Tags: linux, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I am using anaconda for python and I face this problem I tried a lot to solve this error, but still not solved.

I used the following commands so far

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

conda install libgcc
```

[image]

in this [link](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/issues/94) a solution provided but I still don't know how to do that

Comment: Images with text : Please replace with text ! Quite an old OS you have there : GLIBCXX_3.4.20 is an object from the **gcc-4.9.x** libstdc++.so.6.0.20 . Please edit your question to include OS name, version, architecture.

Comment: I could solve this problem by removing and installing Anaconda after a lot of effort that I could not solve it. thanks for your comment

Answer (score 22):

I solved this by

```
conda install libgcc=5.2.0
```

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me as of April 26, 2020. Latest conda on that date.

Comment: libgcc is (apparently) only available in the conda-forge channel, so if you have a standard Anaconda installation, the correct command is `conda install -c conda-forge libgcc=5.2.0`!

Answer (score 22):

This is because you have some old versions not cleaned up while upgrading gcc.

First of all, make sure that you have the latest lib with `conda install -c conda-forge libstdcxx-ng`

1. Find all your lib versions with `find / -name "libstdc++.so*"`. My latest version is 6.0.30.

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.29
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.so.6.0.29
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.so.6.0
/opt/conda/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.29
/opt/conda/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/opt/conda/envs/xxx/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.30
/opt/conda/envs/xxx/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/opt/conda/pkgs/libgcc-7.2.0-h69d50b8_2/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
/opt/conda/pkgs/libstdcxx-ng-12.1.0-ha89aaad_16/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.30
/opt/conda/pkgs/libstdcxx-ng-12.1.0-ha89aaad_16/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/opt/conda/pkgs/libstdcxx-ng-12.1.0-ha89aaad_16/lib/libstdc++.so
```

2. Copy the file to the folder where you are working at and only have the old versions. `/opt/conda/lib/` or `/opt/conda/envs/xxx/lib/`

For example, I'm working on `/opt/conda/lib/`

```
cp /opt/conda/pkgs/libstdcxx-ng-12.1.0-ha89aaad_16/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.30 /opt/conda/lib/
```

3. Remove the old files and link the latest lib. Please repeat these steps for other folders.

```
cd /opt/conda/lib/
rm libstdc++.so.6.0.29
rm libstdc++.so.6.0
ln -s libstdc++.so.6.0.30 libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I have tried many other suggestions and this finally worked!

Answer (score 15):

A solution that worked for me was:

`conda install -c anaconda libstdcxx-ng`

Comment: `conda update libstdcxx-ng` works for me

Comment: This worked for me! I was using `scikit-image` within TensorFlow for image augmentation.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar problem.

```
ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found
```

I've solved it. Steps as follows:

```
try conda install -c anaconda libstdcxx-ng, // didn't work
try conda update libstdcxx-ng // didn't work too
```

But when I execute the command: `locate libstdc++.so.6`, found amazing things such as: /root/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26, which apparently is newer than .so.6.0.

I try:

```
strings /root/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26 | grep GLIBC
see [GLIBCXX_3.4.20][1]
```

That's the file I want to find.

Next step: `ls -l  /root/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26` - Check the file is true, not a link.

Next step: copy /root/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26 to /lib64.

Next step: `ls -l /lib64/libstdc++.so.6` - It's a soft link, so I can remove it without worry.

Next step: rm -rf /lib64/libstdc++.so.6

Next step: make a new soft link by:
ln -s libstdc++.so.6.0.26 libstdc++.so.6

That's all. I run my code without error.

God give me wisdom, Glory to God!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed step-by-step procedure. Worked for me to install rstudio server.

Answer (score 3):

I meet the same problem, which is when I run `jupyter notebook`, I got

`` ImportError: /home/cugtyt/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../.././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/cugtyt/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../../libzmq.so.5) ``

I solve it by doing this:

`conda uninstall gcc`

Hope it can help u!

Answer (score 2):

I use anaconda, the following commands works for me:

```
conda install libgcc
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
cd /path/to/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib
ln -s libstdc++.so.6.0.30 libstdc++.so.6
```

you can add `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to ~/.bashrc file.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error for `import matplotlib` statement in Python. There is no need to install anything more. The reason this error occurred because this lib cannot be found on path. To fix it, add this in .bashrc:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/
```

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 22.04
Originally I have `libstdcxx-ng=11.2.0` in my env.
Then I use `conda install -c conda-forge libstdcxx-ng` to update it to a higher version, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Since `libgcc=5.2.0` is not available from conda.
I solve it by this:

```
conda uninstall cmake
pip install cmake
```

Answer (score 0):

I use mamba (a faster alternative to conda)

```bash
mamba install libgcc
```

Than it works.

Answer (score -1):

Re-installing scipy library corrected the error automatically for me.

```
conda install scipy
```