# scipy not using anaconda's local lib for libgcc

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, anaconda, libgcc

I'm using `Anaconda 4.10.3`, with `Python 3.9.7`, `Scipy 1.7.1` on `Ubuntu 16.04.6`. A script I need to run uses Scipy's optimize and it throws the following error:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /home/user/anaconda3/envs/work/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_group_columns.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

As indicated in the error, the system `libstcc++.so.6` does not provide `GLIBCXX_3.4.26`, which I verified using

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```

Then I ran `conda install libgcc` and verified that `strings /home/user/anaconda3/envs/work/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.29 | grep GLIBCXX` shows `GLIBCXX_3.4.26`. I then added the following line to my `.bashrc` and ran `source ~/.bashrc`

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/anaconda3/envs/work/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

When I run the script after this, I still get the same error saying  `ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found`.

I was thinking of downgrading scipy, but shouldn't there be a better way to fix this without downgrading?

Answer (score 4):

I am having the same issue crop up using Anaconda3 (4.10.3), Python 3.7.12, and Scipy 1.7.3.  Changing my PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my .bashrc did not fix the issue.

After some searching, it seems to be a conda dependency issue:
[Anaconda libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453497/anaconda-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found)

I was able to fix the issue by running
`conda update libstdcxx-ng`